# Manual change of shape in ggplot2 changes colors from solid to outline?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

My overall goal is to have solid colored shapes outlined in black.

I am having trouble formatting the shapes and colors in my scatter plot in ggplot2.  I want the shapes based on location, and the colors based on time.  This works well, yet as I manually change the shapes using `scale_shape_manual()`, since the crosses are very difficult to see. The color changes from fill to outline, shown below.

[image] Goes to: [image]

I have tried re-organizing the order I present the variables within `aes()`, using `fill =` instead of `color =` , creating individual `geom_point()` layers, and manually changing the color scale with `scale_color_manual()`.  My original code is:

```
p <- ggplot(data=data.scores,aes(x=NMDS1,y=NMDS2))+
  geom_point(aes(shape=Location, color=Time), size=3) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(0,1,2,5))
```

I also have `theme()` script after what is shown above, but I have removed those because I have verified they don't influence my issue.  Additionally, I would ideally outline the points in black using pch, shown below:

```
p <- ggplot(data=data.scores,aes(x=NMDS1,y=NMDS2))+
      geom_point(aes(shape=Location, color=Time), color = "black", pch=21, size=3) +
      scale_shape_manual(values = c(1,2,0,5))
```

yet, this just turns the points to all black circles:

[image]

I have used `scale_shape_manual()` and `pch =` before without any issues, and I am at a loss.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

J

Comment: Could you share part of your data using `dput(data.scores)`? It will be easier to help.

Comment: edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
ggplot(data.scores, aes(x=NMDS1, y=NMDS2, group=Location,fill=Time,color=Time)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=Location,color=Time),size=3,stroke = 1)+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21:24))+ 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('red','pink','green','blue'))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('red','pink','green','blue'))
```

[image]

Also try this for your main issue:

```
ggplot(data.scores, aes(x=NMDS1, y=NMDS2, group=Time,fill=Time,color=Time)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=Location),colour = "black", size = 4)+
  geom_point(aes(shape=Location,color=Time),size=3)+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21:24))+ 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('red','pink','green','blue'))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('red','pink','green','blue'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Duck! I was able to create the image you show there, but it doesn't include location based on shape?  Also there are no black outlines.

Comment: @Geomicro I have updated the solution. Let me know if this worked for your goal.

Comment: @Geomicro I added another piece for the borders. It can be helpful.

Comment: Ahhh yes.  Gorgeous. Thank you Duck.

Answer (score 0):

The [*Shape* aesthetic specifications](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html#sec:shape-spec) are your friend. Specifically, `shape = 21`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.scores, aes(NMDS1, NMDS2, fill = Location)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>